# how to configure apache to view hidden (`.`) files?

Tags: apache, apache2, apache-config, directory-listing

How do I make a directory listing in apache show the `.`/hidden files? I tried both

```
    <Directory /var/www/*>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

and

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

but neither show the hidden files

Answer (score 5):

check what your IndexIgnore is set to. On mine, it's:

`/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/autoindex.conf:IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# RCS CVS *,v *,t`

---

Obviously, you'd want to remove that `.??*`

Comment: or override it in a vhost conf file, or with .htaccess

Comment: you should also make sure, that access is allowed to those files (^.ht.* files are usually denied by default)